# Datatable en jquery no se está actualizando en el DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

Estoy realizando una chrome extension y quiero que los datos se muestren usando un dataTable pero al añadir datos mediante AngularJs aparecen en la datatable pero por ejemplo las entries y la busqueda no muestran los datos recientemente añadidos hasta que se recarga la pagina

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['ags','switch'], function(data){
        $rootScope.test = [];
        $rootScope.isEmpty = true;
        $rootScope.table;
        if(data.ags!=undefined){
            $rootScope.test = data.ags;
            $rootScope.isEmpty = false;
        }
        if(data.switch!=undefined){
            $rootScope.switch = data.switch;
        }
        else
            $rootScope.switch = false;

        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $rootScope.tabla = $('#rowTable').DataTable({
                "ordering": false,
                "deferRender": true
                    });
        });
}])

<table ng-hide="!test.length || showReset" 
       id="rowTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table_name"> Nombre </th>
            <th class="table_ip"> Ip </th>
            <th class="table_actions">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in test track by $index" ng-cloak ng-
       click="changeUrl(row)" ng-class="{rowOn: row.is_on}">
            <td class="table_name">{{row.name}}</td>
            <td class="table_ip">{{row.ip}}</td>
            <td class="table_actions">
                <i class="material-icons material-icons-m"
                   ng-click="edit($index); $event.stopPropagation()">mode_edit</i>
                <i class="material-icons material-icons-m"
                   ng-click="delete($index); $event.stopPropagation()">delete</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> <br>
```

Añado aquí la funcion tal cual que uso para añadir datos

```
$scope.new = function(){
    $rootScope.test.push(({"name": 
    document.getElementById('name').value,"ip": 
    document.getElementById('ip').value ,"is_on": false}));
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'ags': $rootScope.test});
}
```

Comment: si estas usando angular, por que usas jQuery esto es una mala practica y por eso suele fallar el DOM

Comment: puedes usar jquery, pero solo en componentes que deberian manipular el DOM como las directivas y siempre que manipules el DOM debes permitir que angular realice el ciclo de `$digest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final solucione mi problema usando la libreria [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/)

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" ng-table="tableParams">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-cloak ng-click="changeUrl(row)" ng-class="{rowOn: row.is_on && switch}">
            <td data-title="'Nombre'" class="table_name" filter="{name: 'text'}">{{row.name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Ip'" class="table_ip" filter="{ip: 'text'}">{{row.ip}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Acciones'" class="table_actions">
                <i class="material-icons material-icons-m" ng-click="edit($index);    $event.stopPropagation()">mode_edit</i>
                <i class="material-icons material-icons-m" ng-click="delete($index); $event.stopPropagation()">delete</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```